# Design considerations for supporting around 400+ concurrent users in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, iis

I am at the start of a mid sized asp.net c# project and with an application performance requirement to be able to support around 400+ concurrent users.

What are the things I need to keep in mind while architecting an application to meet such performance and availability standards? The page need to be served in under 5 seconds. I plan to have the application and database on separate physical machines. From a coding and application layering perspective:-

- If I have the database layer exposed to the application layer via a
  WCF service, will it hamper the performance? Should I use a direct
  tcp connection instead?
- Will it matter if I am using Entity framework or some other ORM or the enterprise library data block?
- Should I log exceptions to database or a text file?
- How do I check while development if the code being built is going to meet those performance standards eventually? Or is this even a point I need to worry about at development stage?
- Do I need to put my database connection code and other classes that hold lookup data that **rarely change** for the life of the application, in static classes so it is available thru the life of the application?
- What kind of caching policy should I apply?
- What free tools can I use to measure and test performance? I know of red-gate performance measurement tools but that has a high license cost, so free tools are what I'd prefer.

I apologize if this question is too open ended. Any tips or thoughts on how I should proceed?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You are concerned about a lot that I would consider micro optimizations, since most likely your app will be database bound. For doing a quick performance test have a look at [Apaches benchmarking tool](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html).

Comment: Thanks. But how do I use that for a .Net application running on IIS?

Comment: For a site sized as you describe, Ants performance profiler is a cheap way to find bottlenecks.  I use and love it, and have typically cut 50% plus off response times as a result, usually within just an hour or so effort.  Using profilers easily pays for themselves.

Comment: ````ab -n 1000 -c 5 http://example.com/index.asp```` will do 1000 requests for that specified page, with 5 requests running simultaneous at any time. The results will look [something like this](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-rJkaSril8dI/TZnX9NnakOI/AAAAAAAAA7M/60G3I9ALzx8/s1600/2.bmp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An important consideration when designing a scalable application is to make it stateless. No sessions. Another important consideration is to cache everything that you can in order to reduce database queries. And this cache should be distributed to other machines which are specifically design to store it. Then all you have to do is throw an additional server when the application starts to run slowly due to an increased user load.

As far as your questions about WCF are concerned, you can use WCF, it won't be a bottleneck for your application. It will definitely add an additional layer which will slow things a bit but if you want to expose a reusable layer that can scale independently on its own WCF is great.

ORMs might indeed introduce a performance slowdown in your application. It's more due to the fact that you have less control over the generated SQL queries and thus more difficult to tune them. This doesn't mean that you shouldn't use an ORM. It's just to be careful about what SQL it spits and tune it with your DB admin. There are also lightweight ORMs such as [dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/), [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) and [Massive](http://eventuallyconsistent.net/2011/05/05/a-massive-orm/) that you might consider.

As far as static classes are concerned, they won't improve performance that much compared to instance classes. A class instantiation on the CLR is a pretty fast operation as [Ayende explains](http://ayende.com/blog/4811/performance-numbers-in-the-pub). Static classes will introduce tight coupling between your data access layer and your consuming layer. So you can forget about static classes for the moment.

For error logging, I would recommend you [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/).

For benchmarking there are quite a lot of tools, [Apanche Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) is one that is simple to use.

Comment: how do I create a login if I am not using sessions?

Comment: @user20358, you use the Forms Authentication provider. It uses cookies to track authenticated users. No server side sessions.

Comment: not having sessions seems like a disadvantage to me at first. How would I pass data between two pages. Not every activity is done on the same page in a postback. some requirements would warrant moving between pages but carrying that data forward via session.

Comment: also, it is possible to use apache for a .Net application running on IIS? The definition talks of... "how many requests per second your Apache installation is capable of serving".

Comment: @user20358, it's a disadvantage that you will have to accept if you want to build scalable applications. In order to pass data between pages there are so many other techniques in the HTTP protocol. For example query strings, HTTP POST verbs, etc... But no sessions. Sessions are the arch enemy of scalability. And yes it is possible to use ab.exe to benchmark any type of application. ab.exe takes an url as parameter, this url could be anything.

Answer (score 2):

There's always a trade-off between developer productivity, maintainability and performance; you can only really make that trade-off sensibly if you can measure. Productivity is measured by how long it takes to get something done; maintainability is harder to measure, but luckily, performance is fairly easy to quantify. In general, I'd say to optimize for productivity and maintainability first, and only optimize for performance if you have a measurable problem.

To work in this way, you need to have performance targets, and a way of regularly assessing the solution against those targets - it's very hard to retro-fit performance into a project. However, optimizing for performance without proven necessity tends to lead to obscure, hard-to-debug software solutions.

Firstly, you need to turn your performance target into numbers you can measure; for web applications, that's typically "dynamic page requests per second". 400 concurrent users probably don't all request pages at exactly the same time - they usually spend some time reading the page, completing forms etc. On the other hand, AJAX-driven sites request a lot more dynamic pages.

Use Excel or something to work from peak concurrent users to dynamic page generations per second based on wait time, requests per interaction, and build in a buffer - I usually over-provision by 50%.

For instance:

400 concurrent users with a session length of 5 interactions and 
2 dynamic pages per interaction means 400 * 5 * 2 = 4000 page requests.

With a 30 seconds wait time, those requests will be spread over 30 * 5 = 150 seconds.

Therefore, your average page requests / second is 4000 / 150 = 27 requests / second.

With a 50% buffer, you need to be able to support a peak of roughly 40 requests / second.

That's not trivial, but by no means exceptional.

Next, set up a performance testing environment whose characteristics you completely understand and can replicate, and can map to the production environment. I usually don't recommend re-creating production at this stage. Instead, reduce your page generations / second benchmark to match the performance testing environment (e.g. if you have 4 servers in production and only 2 in the performance testing environment, reduce by half).

As soon as you start developing, regularly (at least once a week, ideally every day) deploy your work-in-progress to this testing environment. Use a load test generator (Apache Benchmark or Apache JMeter work for me), write load tests simulating typical user journeys (but without the wait time), and run them against your performance test environment. Measure success by hitting your target "page generations / second" benchmark. If you don't hit the benchmark, work out why (Redgate's ANTS profiler is your friend!).

Once you get closer to the end of the project, try to get a test environment that's closer to the production system in terms of infrastructure. Deploy your work, and re-run your performance tests, increasing the load to reflect the "real" pages / second requirement. At this stage, you should have a good idea of the performance characteristics of the app, so you're really only validating your assumptions. It's usually a lot harder and more expensive to get such a "production-like" environment, and it's usually a lot harder to make changes to the software, so you should use this purely to validate, not to do the regular performance engineering work.